# Remote desktop TO Windows CE ... over USB?

Tags: windows-ce, remote-desktop

Is there any way to remote-desktop INTO a Windows CE device if all I have to work with on that device is a USB port? I'd like to be able to record the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveSync supports *ActiveSync Remote Display*.   And ActiveSync works via USB.   See if your WinCE device supports ActiveSync.

Otherwise, you could do something with VNC and a USB network adaptor, provided there were drivers for it on CE.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best free Windows *Mobile* 5/6 remote desktop tool I've found:  http://www.mymobiler.com/

To use this, you will need to ActiveSync the device to your PC/Laptop via the USB cable.

I'm not positive if it works the same in raw Windows CE.

Answer (score 2):

Something like [SOTI PocketController](http://www.soti.net/PCPro/Default.aspx) maybe?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download WindowsMobilePowerToys.msi from [enter link description here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10601)
2. Install it
3. Connect CE device via USB cable with PC
4. Go to directory on PC C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile Developer Power Toys\ActiveSync_Remote_Display\devices\wce400
5. Choose your CE processor. 4 example, my CE processor is armv4.
6. Copy cerdisp2.exe file from directory to CE device, \Windows directory
7. Go to C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile Developer Power Toys\ActiveSync_Remote_Display on PC and run file ASRDisp.exe

Answer (score 1):

The best software I ever seen for controlling the mobile devices over active sync is 
[EveryWAN Remote Support Personal Edition](http://download.cnet.com/EveryWAN-Remote-Support-Personal-Edition/3000-18482_4-10906989.html)

If you want to control the mobile device over IP, you can by using VNC Viewer in the PC and 
[EfonVNC](https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=154944&package_id=172386&release_id=661777) on the device.